# How to define variable in matpotlib while making an histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make an histogram from a CSV file using age and gender. The problem is the gender has 3 value (Male, Female and Unknown). I only want to use Male and Female with their record number by age. My code is:

```
#plt.figure(figsize=[10,8])
gender = data_dict['Gender']
age = data_dict['Age']
legend = ['Male', 'Female']

plt.hist([age, gender], color = ['red','blue'], bins = 10, edgecolor = 'black')
plt.xticks(range(15, 80))
plt.yticks(range(57, 66309))
plt.legend(legend)

plt.title('Age of Accident Victims')
plt.xlabel('Ages')
plt.ylabel('Record Number')
plt.show()
```

[image: The Y-axis is totally messed up]

Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: to visualize your problem it would be better if you added only the plot, without code part in image

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that directly from within the matplotlib function, but you can easily remove the data points you are not interested in before doing the histogram. For example:

```
gender_clean = []
age_clean = []
for gender_point, age_point in zip(gender, age):
    if gender_point != 'Unknown':
        gender_clean.append(gender_point)
        age_clean.append(age_point)
```

Or using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
age = np.array(age)[np.array(gender) != 'Unknown']
gender = np.array(gender)[np.array(gender) != 'Unknown']
```